# Arduino code - Why do we need to read the rising edge?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, code, edge

I'm having a difficult time figuring out why we need to read the rising edge instead of using both edges.

We are doing a school lab using interrupts in Arduino code, and I understand that we need the interrupt to read the rising edge, but **why are we reading the rising edge**?

The question that I am specifically trying to answer is part B of the following:

*Write a paragraph explaining how you are measuring frequency.  Be sure to include:*

*a. why you must use an interrupt.*

*b. why you enabled the interrupt on the RISING edge, instead of both transitions.*

c.  Comment on the accuracy of your Arduino's frequency measurements

Comment: What would happen if you used both? Hint: is the time between rising and falling the same as between falling and rising? If you use rising or falling, witch (sic) makes more sense, or is there any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, they expect you to answer based on the lab or lecture, not based on actual use.

There is no reason you have to interrupt on the Rising Edge instead of the Falling Edge, or the other way round, or both. [Or edge interrupt instead of level interrupt.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt)

**Your design determines which type of interrupt you need.** A signal that is active low will need a falling edge or level low interrupt, while a active high signal will need a rising edge or level high interrupt.

Sometimes you want to interrupt on both sides of the signal, like from a sensor or button. Someone pressed a button, and you want to do x when it's pressed, and y when it's released.  Or you're timing how long the signal goes from one state to the other. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure frequency, then you have to measure number of pulses in a specified time or time period between two pulses. In any case you have to start/stop at the same threshold of a signal begin or end, but with use of both edges won't give you the frequency, but the pulse duration

Comment: It would work equally well to use the falling edge. The point is that you should only use one of the two, even if the question is a little badly worded.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have to* use interrupts, and you don't *have to* use only the rising edge for measuring frequency.  These are design choices of your system.

Think about how you are measuring the frequency.  There are two basic ways, counting cycles during a fixed time, or measuring the time per cycle.  Think of how you'd do each of these on a human scale if the frequency you were trying to measure was slow enough.

The rising edge interrupt is like getting a click every cycle.  You could look at your watch, and count clicks for some fixed period, like 15 seconds.  The other method would be using a stopwatch.  You start it on one click, then stop it on the next.

Now consider how getting a interrupt (click) on both the rising and falling edges would mess up either of these procedures.  You could adjust for the difference, but what happens if the time from falling to rising edge is different than from rising to falling edge?